# How do I pick up Ether after Crowdsale? And other questions

Tags: solidity, crowdsale

Testnet: Rinkeby
Address token: 0xeAD7ACF95b260E4C866a036F9E792759Ba0Ad4ce
Address Crowdsale:0xf2D4B282CE60A0abBE7fb74C694A9A04087E5519

Ethers credited at the end of Crowdsale: 0x8be6c677cd26d8836bf75bf22fa651c463072a61

Token and Crowdsale implemented in OpenZeppelin 2.5

1. How can I take ether to the contract creator's wallet?
2. How to make a refund if the amount collected is less than SoftCup?
3. What code should I add to limit the minimum and maximum investor contribution?

The code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.5;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/emission/AllowanceCrowdsale.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/validation/TimedCrowdsale.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/distribution/RefundableCrowdsale.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/validation/CappedCrowdsale.sol";

contract Sale is Crowdsale, AllowanceCrowdsale, TimedCrowdsale, CappedCrowdsale, RefundableCrowdsale {  
    constructor(
    uint256 _rate,
    address payable _wallet,
    ERC20 _token,
    address _tokenWallet,
    uint256 _openingTime,
    uint256 _closingTime,
    uint256 _cap,
    uint256 _goal
  )
    AllowanceCrowdsale(_tokenWallet)
    Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)
    CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
    TimedCrowdsale(_openingTime, _closingTime)
    RefundableCrowdsale(_goal)
    public
    {
    require(_goal <= _cap);  
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Since RefundableCrowdsale inherits from FinalizableCrowdsale you can call finalize to move funds from the escrow contract to the configured wallet.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this correctly?

Comment: After the sale has ended if the goal was reached it is possible for anyone to call finalize on the Sale contract. The function will move funds from the escrow contract to the beneficiary the address configured as _wallet in the Sale creation.